# Find point using distance from any other point with minimum steps

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming

I need to find a point in 3d space with a function that returns the distance between that point and any other point of my choosing. all the coordinates can vary from 0 to 100 and only can be integers. Of course, I could use brute force, but the complexity will be n^3, and that’s way too far from minimum steps

I was trying to reach the solution using binary search, because we can imagine, that I have an array from 0 to 100, where each point represents some axis, x-axis for example. And by moving either to the left or to the right I will be moving closer to the point, but my solution does not work correctly

This is the code I could come up with. At some points it works, but not all

```
const findClosestX = (low, high, destinationPoint) => {
  const middle = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);

  const starting_distance = new Point(middle, 0, 0).getDistance(destinationPoint);

  // Point class is simple object with x,y,z coordinates and function
  // for getting distance between points
  const distance_1 = new Point(low, 0, 0).getDistance(destinationPoint);
  const distance_2 = new Point(high, 0, 0).getDistance(destinationPoint);

  const minPoint = Math.min(starting_distance, distance_1, distance_2);

  if (minPoint === starting_distance) {
    return middle;
  } else if (minPoint === distance_1) return findClosestX(low, middle - 1, destinationPoint);
  else if (minPoint === distance_2) return findClosestX(middle + 1, high, destinationPoint);
};
```

Comment: You say you already have "_a predefined point_", what do you mean with "_I need to find this predefined point_"?

Comment: It would be useful to post your code, an answer would also be in code but why invent something instead of using your actual framework?

Comment: It's also unclear if the coordinates are integer or floating-point. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/kou02frn/1/) is a solution for the floating-point case, based on a 3d version of bisection method. It can be adapted for the integer version too.

Comment: @kikon, your solution is great! It finds the point efficiently enough, could you please elaborate on how it works? I'd be so delighted to take a look at it and I'm sure it'll help others too

Comment: right away - so, the coordinates are not integer, right?

Comment: @kikon I already adjusted it to work in integer field, but you could do the way is easier for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the one-dimensional case there's [the bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) which is the continuous version of the well known [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

It is used to find the solution of an equation,
that is the zero of a function f(x) = 0, in an interval [a, b],
where the function is monotonous (increasing or decreasing),
and f(a) > 0 and f(b) < 0 (or f(a) < 0, f(b) > 0),
which guarantees that there is exactly one solution
in the interval [a, b].

It consists in a loop that maintains three points: left, right and middle.

- Initially, they are the a, b and (a+b)/2.
- At each step it updates the three points by either:

  1. choosing the middle point to be the next left point (chooses the right half,
     the new interval is [middle, right])
  2. choosing the middle point to be the right point
     (chooses the left half, the new interval is [left, middle]).

  The next middle will be computed as the middle of the new interval.
- the choice between the variants above is made in such a way
  that the sign of the f(left) is the same as the sign of f(a) and
  the sign of the f(right) is the same as f(b). This guarantees that
  the solution is always inside the interval [left, right] and
  since the interval is always shrinking (it's half the length
  of the interval in the previous step) it's guaranteed to
  get ever close to the true solution.
- the iteration is stopped when the current middle point
  is close enough to the solution |f(middle)| < eps

---

The first step in adjusting this algorithm to the problem
here is the most sensitive: *making the algorithm work
for an optimization problem*. I'll restrict the analysis
to a minimization problem, as it is the case here.

The change in the algorithm is trivial: from the points
{left, middle, right}, we choose the two with the minimal value
of f. That is if f(left) < f(right), we chose [left, middle]
and if f(left) > f(right), we choose [middle, right].

However, care should be taken that **this algorithm is
convergent for a minimization problem only in very special cases**.
A sufficient condition for the algorithm to converge (that is
fortunately satisfied by the Euclidean distance) is that
the function f is *symmetrical with respect to
its minimum* in the interval we work with:
f(x<sub>min</sub> - d) = f(x<sub>min</sub> + d), when
x<sub>min</sub> - d and x<sub>min</sub> + d are inside the
interval [a, b].

---

The second step now is to extend the above algorithm for
a 3-dimensional minimization problem. Instead of the
interval [a, b] we start with the initial cube (eight 3d points)
and its center.

In the next step we choose the
point among the eight corners that has the minimum f(x, y, z) - from that point and the center as diagonally opposite we form
a new cube - that is we chose one of the eight "half-cubes"
of the previous cube determined by the center.

The symmetry condition in this case can be written as f(x<sub>min</sub>±dx, y<sub>min</sub>±dy, z<sub>min</sub>±dz) = f(x<sub>min</sub>∓dx, y<sub>min</sub>∓dy, z<sub>min</sub>∓dz)

Here's the code for the continuous case (i.e., the coordinates are floating point numbers):

```js
const x0 = Math.random()*100, y0 = Math.random()*100, z0 = Math.random()*100;
console.log('Original point', [x0, y0, z0]);

function dist(x, y, z){
     return Math.sqrt((x-x0)*(x-x0)+(y-y0)*(y-y0)+(z-z0)*(z-z0));
}

//utility function
function makeCube([xA, yA, zA], [xB, yB, zB]){
     return {
          cube:     [[xA, yA, zA],[xB, yA, zA],[xA, yB, zA],[xA, yA, zB],
               [xA, yB, zB], [xB, yB, zA], [xB, yA, zB], [xB, yB, zB]],
          center: [(xA+xB)/2, (yA+yB)/2, (zA+zB)/2]
     }
}

//utility function
function minIndex(a){
     return a.reduce(([minValue, minIndex], xi, i) => xi < minValue ? [xi, i] : [minValue, minIndex], [1/0, -1]);
}

function findPoint(eps = 1e-5, NMAX = 10000){
     let A = [0, 0, 0], B = [100, 100, 100];
     for(let i = 0; i < NMAX; i++){
          let {cube, center} = makeCube(A, B);
          const d = cube.map(p=>dist(...p));
          const [dMin, iMin] = minIndex(d);
          if(dMin < eps){
               return center;
          }
          A = cube[iMin];
          B = center;
     }
     
     return null; // failed after NMAX iterations
}

console.log('Found point', findPoint())
```

and its adaptation for the case the coordinates are integers

```js
const x0 = Math.floor(Math.random()*101), y0 = Math.floor(Math.random()*101), z0 = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
console.log('Original point', [x0, y0, z0]);

function dist(x, y, z){
     return Math.sqrt((x-x0)*(x-x0)+(y-y0)*(y-y0)+(z-z0)*(z-z0));
}

//utility function
function makeCube([xA, yA, zA], [xB, yB, zB]){
     return {
          cube:     [[xA, yA, zA],[xB, yA, zA],[xA, yB, zA],[xA, yA, zB],
               [xA, yB, zB], [xB, yB, zA], [xB, yA, zB], [xB, yB, zB]],
          center: [Math.round((xA+xB)/2), Math.round((yA+yB)/2), Math.round((zA+zB)/2)]
     }
}

//utility function
function minIndex(a){
     return a.reduce(([minValue, minIndex], xi, i) => xi < minValue ? [xi, i] : [minValue, minIndex], [1/0, -1]);
}

function findPoint(NMAX = 10000){
     let A = [0, 0, 0], B = [100, 100, 100];
     for(let i = 0; i < NMAX; i++){
          let {cube, center} = makeCube(A, B);
          const d = cube.map(p=>dist(...p));
          const [dMin, iMin] = minIndex(d);
          if(dMin === 0){
               console.log(i+' steps');
               return cube[iMin];
          }
          A = cube[iMin];
          B = center;
     }
     
     return null; // failed after NMAX iterations
}

console.log('Found point', findPoint())
```

Note that in both cases an optimization can be made by reusing the previously computed distance for the point in the new cube that was inherited from the previous cube, but I feel that it would make the code less readable.

---

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is indeed helpful and I hope somebody like me will appreciate the solution!